# How to install Neovim on Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

How can I install [Neovim](http://neovim.org/) on Ubuntu? Should I compile it from source?

The [installation steps](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) are a little bit blurry for me...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### From the universe repo

```
sudo apt install neovim
```

### From source

0. Download the master branch from Github
1. Install the dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf automake cmake libncurses5-dev g++
   ```
2. Go to the root of the project and build

   ```
   make cmake
   make test
   ```
3. Run `nvim` in `/neovim-master/build/bin`

That works for me.

### From the PPA repository

0. Add the repository

   ```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
   ```
1. Update and install

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install neovim
   ```

Comment: After that you might want to create a symlink in /usr/bin to point to `nvim` location so that it is indirectly included in your $PATH.

Comment: I would suggest creating a symlink in `~/bin` and adding that directory to your path. This makes it easier to add other scripts to your PATH too.

Comment: Might need to install `libtool-bin`, as well.

Answer (score 11):

According to [official Wiki](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#ubuntu):

> Neovim has been added to a Personal Package Archive which allows you
>   to install it using apt-get on Ubuntu 12.04 and later

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

Prerequisites for the Python modules:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python3-dev python3-pip
```

Comment: You still have to install Python modules by hand, which sucks IMHO.

Comment: See [this wiki section](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#python-support-isnt-working) for the three easy steps to install python modules.

Answer (score 7):

Now you can simply do:

```
sudo apt install neovim
```

Comment: This version is usually very old. It's better to use ppa.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim.appimage
chmod u+x nvim.appimage
./nvim.appimage
```

from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim

It just downloads standalone appimage. u can place it in path if you want to excute it from anywhere. Works on ALL DISTRIBUTIONS

Answer (score 0):

I followed the;

```bsh
git clone **; 
cd neovim; 
make cmake
make test
```

ended up with nvim that worked, but isn't integrated with the system. I might leave him a few weeks/months to get it into some sort of state. But it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with `sudo apt install neovim` or `sudo snap install nvim --classic` but in both cases you will not get the latest version of neovim, with apt being the worst of the two.

The best way to install **the latest version of Neovim** - and keep it up to date - is by using [bob](https://github.com/MordechaiHadad/bob/releases):

```sh
wget https://github.com/MordechaiHadad/bob/releases/download/<version>/bob-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip bob-linux-x86_64.zip
cd bob-linux-x86_64/
chmod +x bob
echo "export PATH=\"/home/<username>/.local/share/bob/nvim-bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
./bob install stable
./bob use stable
```